# Jenkins Pipeline - Iteration on stage level

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've been reaching to a point that I really want to use iteration to save redundant code on stage level when building multi-platforms.
Below is showcasing what I'm trying to do:

```
def map = [
        Bob  : 42,
        Alice: 54,
        Max  : 33
]

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        map.each { entry ->
            stage ($entry.key) {
                steps{
                    timestamps{
                        echo "$entry.value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think the concept here is pretty straight forward, but the builds are failing by telling me:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 13: Expected a stage @ line 13, column 9.
           map.each { entry ->
           ^

WorkflowScript: 12: No stages specified @ line 12, column 5.
       stages {
       ^

2 errors
```

Does this mean jenkins have not yet support user to iterate on stages? If there's anything wrong with what I did, please let me know. Thanks!

-----EDIT------

BTW, @NonCPS is also tried, I don't think this is a `each` problem in pipeline script...

```
def map = [
        Bob  : 42,
        Alice: 54,
        Max  : 33
]

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        iter_stages map
    }
}

@NonCPS
def iter_stages(dd) {
    dd.each { entry ->
        stage ($entry.key) {
            steps{
                timestamps{
                    echo "$entry.value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

OP was in the right direction, but there are a few issues with the code:

- The code to create dynamic stages needs to be in a `script` block.
- You need at least one stage with steps so that you can put the above logic
- You don't need `steps` inside a dynamic stage (probably because it is in `script` block, which means it is no longer declarative).
- The value passed to stage name has a syntax error, it is probably a typo

Here is the code that works the way the OP wants:

```
def map = [
        Bob  : 42,
        Alice: 54,
        Max  : 33
]

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                script {
                    map.each { entry ->
                        stage (entry.key) {
                            timestamps{
                                echo "$entry.value"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how the pipeline will look like:

[image: Pipeline view]

Since this is so dynamic anyway, it should probably use the scripted pipeline syntax instead of the above (which is declarative pipeline), which also makes it possible to avoid the `Initialize` stage.

```
def map = [
        Bob  : 42,
        Alice: 54,
        Max  : 33
]

node {
    map.each { entry ->
        stage (entry.key) {
            timestamps{
                echo "$entry.value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the stage is repeated as shown below
Then the script leads to stackoverflow(:)) error\n
    stages {
        stage('Stage1') {
 ...
                    map.each { entry ->
                        stage (entry.key) { . }
                ...
            }
        }

        stage('Stage2') {
 ...
                    map.each { entry ->
                        stage (entry.key) { . }
                ...
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @vikaspachisia Try wrapping the inner `stage` blocks in a `script` block.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you. I don't really know why you want to iterate on stages and not just iterate your function inside a step of a stage:

```
def map = [
        Bob  : 42,
        Alice: 54,
        Max  : 33
]

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('loop') {
            steps {
                loopNames(map)
            }
        }
    }
}

def loopNames(map){
    map.each { 
        key, value -> println "Age of " + key + " is " + value + ".";
    }
}
```

Call a `groovy function` in your pipeline and pass `map` as parameter.
Below the pipeline I define the content of the function.

```
Output of this run:
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (loop)
[Pipeline] echo
Age of Bob is 42.
[Pipeline] echo
Age of Alice is 54.
[Pipeline] echo
Age of Max is 33.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, the reason I want to do it on stage level is because the keys are stage names. Say I have multiple platforms as keys, and the values are different configurations for different platforms. I want each stage to represent one platform build.

Comment: Why not using parameters for the names and use `when` to check if the parameter value is what you expect. If not the stage is skipped

Comment: Ah, I think there’s some misunderstanding. I need to have those stages tuning in parallel when I get a iteration solution from this. If I’m using “when” conditions, that makes no difference, right? Please correct me if I’m not reading your idea right.